# Firebase import not initializing in constructor ionic native

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, npm, ionic3, ionic-native

I am working on **ionic** fcm push notifications. I have imported

`import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase';` but I not able to initialize `Firebase` in constructor. This is my code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class FcmProvider {

  constructor(private platform: Platform, 
              public firebaseNative:Firebase,
              public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello FcmProvider Provider');
  }

  // Get permission from the user
  async getToken() {
    let token;

    if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      token = await this.firebaseNative.getToken()
    }      
  }
  }
}
```

I am getting error at

```
constructor(private platform: Platform, 
              public firebaseNative:Firebase,
```

It is saying

> Cannot find name Firebase

I am following [this article](https://medium.com/hirewithparam/independent-notification-service-using-ionic-node-fcm-5cdde219480a).

I have installed *npm i @ionic-native/firebase* and *npm i @ionic-native/fcm* packages still not getting it. For more information see screenshot :

[image]

**Update:** Please **`Package.Json`**

```
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/fcm": "^5.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "^5.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.0.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase": "2.0.5",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^5.8.3",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.1.0",
    "nvm-win": "^0.2.4",
    "reinstall": "^2.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.29"
  },
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please share you package.json file or the version of the package

Comment: did you try with this? `import * as firebase from "firebase/app";`

Comment: @MustafaLokhandwala - We haven't tried this yet and things whatever given as a answer. Need some time to give a try. For sure, i'll let know this. Thank you.

Comment: Sure no issues.

Answer (score 2):

May be you are using ionic version 3 project and you are using 
 of latest version ionic V4.

> first solution

As mentioned in v4 Document use "ngx" at the last of import path

Like:-

import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase/ngx';
REF : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase

> Second Solution

First remove the existing plugin 
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase

Re add it with

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase

npm install --save @ionic-native/firebase@4

Remember to follow doc v3  for further implementation

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/firebase/

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using an Angular version that is greater than Angular 6 you need to include `/ngx` at the end of the import. I.e. `import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase/ngx';`

Answer (score 2):

The error comes if you have installed the wrong native plugin version for your project type or you are not appending **ngx** at the end of the import.

Check the project type in **ionic.config.json**

If the type is "**ionic-angular**" (generally Ionic 3), then install 4.x.x version.

```
npm i -s @ionic-native/firebase@4
```

If the type is **"angular"** (generally Ionic 4), then install the latest version

```
npm i -s @ionic-native/firebase
```

Note:

Add ngx at the end of import only if you are using Angular 6

```
import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase/ngx';
```

if not remove ngx from the import

```
import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase'
```

**Refencence**:https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15225#issuecomment-414074074